# Visual Studio 2010 Web Performance Test / Load tests / Coded UI Tests. ANYONE REALLY USE THESE?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2010

I can find some articles on how to use them but I can't seem to find anywhere peoples impression of them using them in real projects. I have been trying to figure out how to use them and I've had alot of problems.

Can someone out there who uses these tools on the job give me thier impression? Are there better alternate tools available? Using these really just a waste of time?

With Coded UI Tests I see how they are good for basic javascript checking but its so basic of a example I don't think it is worth it. With web tests I like how they work but when I activate code coverage/ASP.NET profiling it doesnt work half the time.

Comment: I'm tentatively planning to use these tools to do testing on a project to be delivered to me at some indeterminate date in the future :-)  Yes, the examples are very simple.  However, the idea is that by writing the tests, you have a simple testing apparatus that will quickly test many things at once.  You can catch SNAFUs faster.

Comment: I think the problem is that its very few companies who are developing in one single language etc except smaller firms. And I think the tools in VS get forgotten when not everyone in the team can use them.

Comment: Other problem is that MSVS2010 in full version are not set up in many companies. Same with MSVS2008 - in my company we have only Professional deployed. And as for MSVS2008 Tester Edition we can't get it even via our MSDN subscription. So how you are going to use it when in most cases you can't even try it?

Comment: Im confused by how MSDN works with that and TFS and TFS cleint access...

So I just run everything offline in trial mode to learn this stuff. But If we officially use it someone needs to figure that out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried both Selenium and Coded UI for integration testing the project I am working on. I wrote a [blog article](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/selenium-vs-coded-ui-my-perspective/) with my impressions.

The bottom line for me is that both Selenium and Coded UI are still far from perfect, but better than manual testing. I am using Selenium right now, though I might revisit CodedUI if a few things would be fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 3):

experience with Selenium and VS Coded UI test for web apps.

Better than manual testing in my eyes, though the tests are at times hard to maintain and often need to be changed manually to make them more robust. Both tools have browser plugins which can generate tests automatically, but this code is generally not very resilient towards changes in the HTML (in case of web apps).

You will be disappointed if you expect an automated test run orders of magnitude faster than a manual tester. I think the aim of the vendors is to get the automated test execute aboit *twice* as fast as a manual tester (that can feel painfully slow if you have a large set of tests).

Answer (score 1):

I have used both selenium 1.0 (currently deprecated 2.0 for my dev environment) and visual studio 2010 web testing. There is no doubt, vs 2010 web testing tool is by far (and i mean by far) better than selenium 1.0 and 2.0 (in beta now) in terms of tooling, robustness and the different kinds of metric you can measure (load balance analysis etc). The one good thing also is that it can run your tests in firefox and other browsers as well(provided you have those browsers installed - i believe. Not sure on that one). Selenium is good and have been around for a while. Has a lot of community support but... it can be frustrating. They are currently in transition to 2.0 so I think things will get better and improve after 2.0. In short, if your development environment is .NET with vs 2010, you will get the best ROI by using of the web testing tools.

Disclaimer: I don't work for Microsoft and I am in no way affiliated with MS. My comment above is based on my experience and my only.

Answer (score 0):

As with (most) all Microsoft tools they will do the job--provided you read plenty of materials to understand how to use them and you understand their limitations.  If you are looking for full-featured, high-quality, relatively intuitive tools then look to RedGate.

Microsoft tools will do everything, but nothing terribly well.